# Debian - Configurar VM como Router - Problema en configurar DMZ & LAN NICs

Tags: linux, debian, networking

Tengo una Máquina virtual con Debian 11 Bullseye montada en VirtualBox 7.0. Necesito configurar esta como router, y ademas setearle una NIC LAN 192.168.10.1/27 y una NIC DMZ 192.168.10.33/27.

No estaría entendiendo como hacerlo. Lo que hice dentro de /etc/netowork/interfaces es lo siguiente:

```
#LAN interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
  address 192.168.10.1
  netmask 255.255.255.224

#DMZ interface
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
  address 192.168.10.33
  netmask 255.255.255.224
```

No sé si es la forma correcta o no.

Cuando hago systemctl restart networking me devuelve los siguientes errores:

```
failed to bringup enp0s8
cannot find device "enp0s8"
```

Como dato extra, tengo iptables e iptables-persistent tambien, no sé si se puede hacer algo por ahí y que quede fijo.

Soy bastante novato en Linux. Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Suena a que estás tratando de definir configuración sobre un dispositivo que no existe. Cual es la salida del comando `ip link show`?

Comment: Hola. El problema era que no estaba definido el segundo adaptador en la VM